# JDBC with Apache Derby throwing java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No current connection

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I'm working in a desktop application where I need to connect to a database to retrieve some data and generate a report. For testing purposes, I created a test DB in Derby with the tables I need and some dummy data in them.

As it is a small app, I decided to work with plain JDBC to make it as lightweight as it can be.

I'm using TDD for developing. I've already tested the method for loading the connection properties from a file and the method for creating a connection to the DB. I got stuck when trying to query the data and populate the objects mapped to that data. This is my code:

```
public class JdbcManager {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER_PROPERTY = "jdbc.driver";
    static final String JDBC_URL_PROPERTY = "jdbc.url";
    static final String JDBC_USER_PROPERTY = "jdbc.username";
    static final String JDBC_PASSWORD_PROPERTY = "jdbc.password";
    static String PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH = "src/main/resources/connection.properties";
    String queryCareers = "SELECT career, name FROM db_career”;

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(JdbcManager.class.getName());

    public List<Career> getCareerList() {
        List<Career> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Career item;
        Connection connection = createConnection(PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH);
        try {
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryCareers);

            while (rs.next()) {
                item = new Career(rs.getString("Career"), rs.getString("name"));
                result.add(item);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, “Error retrieving Career data”, ex);
        }

        return result;
    }

    // This method is working correctly according to my tests
    Connection createConnection(String configFilePath) {
        Properties connectionProperties = loadPropertiesFromFile(configFilePath);
        try {
            Class driverClass = Class.forName(connectionProperties.getProperty(JDBC_DRIVER_PROPERTY));
            LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Driver loaded: {0}", driverClass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Driver not found”, ex);
        }

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                connectionProperties.getProperty(JDBC_URL_PROPERTY),
                connectionProperties.getProperty(JDBC_USER_PROPERTY),
                connectionProperties.getProperty(JDBC_PASSWORD_PROPERTY))) {
            LOG.log(Level.INFO, “Connection created: {0}", connection);
            return connection;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, “Unable to connect to DB”, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    // This method is working correctly according to my tests
    Properties loadPropertiesFromFile(String configFilePath) {
        File configFile = new File(configFilePath);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(configFile));
            LOG.log(Level.INFO, “Properties loaded: {0}", properties);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "File not found", ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error reading the file", ex);
        }

        return properties;
    }

}
```

Then I have the failing test:

```
@Test
public void testGetCareerList() {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "testGetCareerList():");
    List<Career> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(
            new Career("LGU", “Some dummy name 1”),
            new Career("TSGU", "Some dummy name 2”));

    // Change the location of the properties file to the testing one
    GestorJdbc.PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH = "src/test/resources/connectionTest.properties";

    List<Career> actualResult = jdbcManager.getCareerList();
    assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);
}
```

And finally the stacktrace when I execute the test:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running ar.edu.unt.jdbc.JdbcManagerTest
jun 06, 2017 7:57:24 PM ar.edu.unt.jdbc.JdbcManagerTest testGetCareerList
INFO: testGetCareerList():
jun 06, 2017 7:57:24 PM ar.edu.unt.jdbc.JdbcManager loadPropertiesFromFile
INFO: Properties loaded: {jdbc.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/siu_test, jdbc.username=dba, jdbc.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver, jdbc.password=dba}
jun 06, 2017 7:57:24 PM ar.edu.unt.jdbc.JdbcManager createConnection
INFO: Driver loaded: class org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
jun 06, 2017 7:57:26 PM ar.edu.unt.jdbc.JdbcManager createConnection
INFO: Connection created: org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40@dc24521
jun 06, 2017 7:57:26 PM ar.edu.unt.jdbc.JdbcManager getCareerList
SEVERE: Error retrieving Career data
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No current connection.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.createStatement(Unknown Source)
    at ar.edu.unt.jdbc.JdbcManager.getCareerList(JdbcManager.java:49)
    at ar.edu.unt.jdbc.JdbcManagerTest.testGetCareerList(JdbcManagerTest.java:71)
    ...
```

I'm working with Netbeans where I have a running Derby DB where I can connect to (as I said, the connection works fine). As you can see by the stacktrace, the Exception is thrown in `createStatement()` but I cannot find the reason.

I've been diving in blogs and post but nothing worked for me. There was a post in some other forum where a user solved his problem by calling `Thread.isInterrupted()` because `createStatement()` is synchronized but didn't work for me as I'm using a single thread for my whole application (in fact, it must be an old post as the method seems not to be available in Java 8, just a similar method called `Thread.interrupted()` or something like that).

If you need more info on my application, let me know in your comments. Any help and/or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `createConnection` is returning a closed connection. You are using a try-with-resources statement to create your connection. This means this connection will be automatically closed at exit of that block, no matter how it is exited (by exception, by return or just end of block).

When you subsequently try to create a statement, the driver reports that you don't have a connection (although the error message itself could be a little more clear).

In short, you should change `createConnection` to:

```
Connection createConnection(String configFilePath) {
    Properties connectionProperties = loadPropertiesFromFile(configFilePath);
    try {
        Class driverClass = Class.forName(connectionProperties.getProperty(JDBC_DRIVER_PROPERTY));
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Driver loaded: {0}", driverClass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Driver not found”, ex);
    }

    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            connectionProperties.getProperty(JDBC_URL_PROPERTY),
            connectionProperties.getProperty(JDBC_USER_PROPERTY),
            connectionProperties.getProperty(JDBC_PASSWORD_PROPERTY))
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, “Connection created: {0}", connection);
        return connection;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, “Unable to connect to DB”, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

BTW: returning `null` on exceptions is really asking for `NullPointerException` elsewhere. Consider just throwing the `SQLException` or creating your own exception.

On the other hand, in `getCareerList` you are not using try-with-resource, while you should, because once you fixed the problem with `createConnection`, you will be leaking resources by not closing them correctly in `getCareerList`. Change it to:

```
try (Connection connection = createConnection(PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH);
     Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryCareers)) {

    //... rest 
} catch (SQLException e) {
    //... rest
}
```

With this the result set, statement and connection will always be correctly closed.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a logical error in the end, (pretty obvious, BTW, shame on me)